# Issue with setting TargetCell in macro copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am new on this forum and seek some help with a macro.
I have two worksheets: one where data are input ("DataEntry") and the other where data are stored ("DataSheet"). The whole idea is that a user can add as many data (s)he wants in the DataEntry worksheet and that all the entries are listed in successive order starting DataSheet!F10 and then move on F11, F12, etc.
I have already used some codes from this forum to do the whole copy paste thing but for some reasons cannot set the TargetCell on F10.
All these entries should have a light yellow font and be numbered starting with 1 in E10, 2 in E11, etc.

Looking forward reading your solutions! Thanks

Here is the coding:

```
Sub ConstrProgramme_addition()

    Dim DataEntry As Worksheet, DataSht As Worksheet
    Dim ItemName As Range, ItemCount As Range
    Dim NRow As Long, TargetCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set DataEntry = .Sheets("DataEntry")
        Set DataSht = .Sheets("Datasheet")
    End With

    With DataEntry
        Set ItemName = .Range("C4")
        Set ItemCount = .Range("E4")
    End With

    With DataSht
        
        If IsEmpty(Range("F10")) = True Then
        Set TargetCell = .Range("F10")
        Else
        Set TargetCell = ActiveCell.Offset(NRow, 0).Select
    
        
        NRow = .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        End If
        
        TargetCell.Resize(ItemCount.Value, 1).Value = ItemName.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you missing a period `.` before `Range("F10")` in this line `IsEmpty(Range("F10"))`?

Comment: Thanks. I added the period. Yet, now Set TargetCell = ActiveCell.Offset(NRow, 0).Select seems to block the macro. Am not sure how to deal with that...

Comment: What do you mean by **"seems to block the macro"**? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error you get?

Comment: `NRow` is set **after** the call to `ActiveCell.Offset(NRow, 0).Select` so there can be no reference to `NRow` (hence the error)

Comment: Get rid of the `.Select`, also are you sure you want to reference the active cell atht hat point? you have aslo not set nrow at the point you are using it,

Comment: Hi Zac, the error message is "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: I got rid of the .Select and put NROw before the call but the macro behaves now weirdly as the first entry appears where it should be (DataSheet F10) but then if I am encoding new entries, these appear in the DataEntry worksheet. Not sure what cause this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten it a little:

```
Sub ConstrProgramme_addition()

    Dim DataEntry As Worksheet, TargetCell As Range

    Set DataEntry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry")
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datasheet")
        Set TargetCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        If TargetCell.Row < 10 Then Set TargetCell = .Range("F10")
        TargetCell.Resize(DataEntry.Range("E4").Value, 1).Value = DataEntry.Range("C4").Value
    End With

End Sub
```